# C# add object to List, reference only one object in the List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am adding objects to a List but when printing it is the same object, the last added object. I do understand that it has to do with references but are not able to find how to solve it. In the If segment ("B") i am doing Resouce.Load of new sprites every time but after the "else", as you can see, I am reusing the same prefab.

At >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<< #1 >>> all looks good but at >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<< #2 >>> only the last object is printed.

```
           List<GameObject> processedContainerGO = newList<GameObject>();

           foreach (GameObject fGO in theContainerList) {

                if (toBeFlippedCard_GO.tag.LastIndexOf ("B") != -1) { // Back is up - load front

                ...CODE

                }
                else { //

                    // GET THE CORRECT TAG NAME
                    convertedCardTag = CardsAndConversions.front2Back [toBeFlippedCard_GO.tag];

                    // LOAD THE BACK SIDE CARD OBJECT
                    flip_GO = Resources.Load("BackSide") as GameObject;

                    // SET CORRECT NAME AND TAG
                    flip_GO.transform.name = convertedCardTag;
                    flip_GO.transform.tag = convertedCardTag;
                }

                //
                flip_GO.transform.localScale = cardScaleVector;

                // POSITION NEW "FLIPPED" OBJECT ON SAME SPOT
                flip_GO.transform.position = originalPosition_v3;

                // PUT THE CORRECT ROTATION
                flip_GO.transform.rotation = originalRotation_Q;
                print ("Add 2 flip_GO: " + flip_GO); >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<< #1 >>>
                processedContainerGO.Add(flip_GO);

                // DESTROY THE CARD THAT SHOULD BE FLIPPED
                Destroy (GameObject.FindWithTag (toBeFlippedCard_GO.tag));

                // INSTANTIATE THE FLIPPED CARD
                temp_GameObject = Instantiate (flip_GO) as GameObject;

        }

        foreach (GameObject aGO in processedContainerGO) print ("processedContainer: " + aGO.tag); >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<< #2 >>>
```

Comment: how are you instantiating the flip_GO in your first if? does the problem persist if you comment out this line? temp_GameObject = Instantiate (flip_GO) as GameObject; Try instantiating a new flip_GO on each pass within your loop.

Comment: I am initiate flip_GO prior to the foreach loop.

Comment: that's the problem. try instantiating it every time you go through the loop so that you are adding a new reference to the list each time.

Comment: Hmm i am trying but no success. Would you be able to recommend how and where?

Comment: try adding flip_GO = new GameObject(); before flip_GO = Resources.Load("BackSide") as GameObject;

Comment: did not work I am afraid, same result :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72490/discussion-between-alex-m-and-peterk).